# Suffix text form field (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to align the price text as it is in the first image, I tried to do it as in the second image, but I could not.

I want to do:

[image: I want to do =>]

The problem:

[image: The problem]

This is the code I wrote to try to build the design.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: startController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
  decoration: const InputDecoration().copyWith(
      border: const UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPinCodeColor)),
  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPinCodeColor)),
  disabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPinCodeColor)),
  suffix: Text('JOD', style: 
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(fontSize: 
      Sizes.textSize_22)),
  ),
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(fontSize: 
      Sizes.textSize_34),
)
```

Comment: As I [just answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72088936/8244632) in one related question, to show the suffix just after the text, the width of the `TextField` should be adjusted according to that. Remove the `end` Alignment and adjust the width, it will be exactly like that.

Comment: How to adjust the width?
border is not null!
If you can rewrite the code to be like the required form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have make custom widget for this purpose. I made `StatefulWidget` I hope it make sense for you.

- `FocusNode` is for handling focus change and animate the line underneath the Text.
- `MouseRagion` is for handling hovering events.
- `IntrinsicWidth` is for making `TextFormInput` expandable while typing.

This is the code:

```
class TextCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextCustom({Key? key, this.textController, this.suffix})
      : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController? textController;
  final String? suffix;
  @override
  State<TextCustom> createState() => _TextCustomState();
}

class _TextCustomState extends State<TextCustom> {
  bool _isHovering = false;
  bool _isFocased = false;

  FocusNode textFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    textFocus.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _isFocased = textFocus.hasFocus;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (event) {
          setState(() {
            _isHovering = true;
          });
        },
        onExit: (event) {
          setState(() {
            _isHovering = false;
          });
        },
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            textFocus.requestFocus();
          },
          child: InputDecorator(
            expands: false,
            isFocused: _isFocased,
            isHovering: _isHovering,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
              textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
              children: [
                IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    focusNode: textFocus,
                    controller: widget.textController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 20),
                      isCollapsed: true,
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                    ),
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .headline6!
                        .copyWith(fontSize: 34),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                (widget.suffix != null)
                    ? Text(
                        'JOD',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline6!
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 22),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Which looks like:]

Comment: حبيب قلبي والله شكراََ كتير

Comment: ولو تكرم عيونك @Mohammed