# Change text fragment in TextFormField and make it static (not changeable) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added the text that is displayed in the `TextFormField`. I need to change the text size of not everything, but only `KWh`, make it smaller + can the `€` and `KWh` values ​​be made static so that they cannot be changed?

**code**

```
TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: _priceController
              ..text = '€' + widget.price.toStringAsFixed(2) + ' KWh',
            style: widget.textStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why `Suffix` and `Prefix` are provided in `InputDecoration`.

To use them for your desired output, do as:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  controller: _priceController
      ..text = widget.price.toStringAsFixed(2),
  style: widget.textStyle,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
  prefix: Text('€',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  suffix: Text('KWh',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
),
```

You can change the `color`, `fontSize`, `fontWeight` or any such TextStyle property by using widgets for `Suffix` and `Prefix`. `Prefix` and `Suffix` stay static and can't be changed/Edited by the user.

Output:

[image]

Do Remember, Suffix is placed at the end of the `TextFormField`, so, you've to adjust the its `width` according to that.

Else, it will look like this with a full width `TextFormField`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This solved my issue.