# Flutter Center align suffixText next to InputControl value

Tags: css, flutter, dart

I'm trying to Center align suffixText next to the input value but unable to do so.
It's pretty straight forward using css though.

What I have tried so far

```
TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Amount',
                  suffixText: "(700INR)", <- Would be dynamic based on input)
                  prefixText: "\$"),
              controller: amountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
            )
```

Tried `Align` and `Center` widget : Current Output.

[image]

Expected output This is what I want to achieve ( Ex using CSS)
[image]

Comment: I think in Flutter it is not possible to move the suffixText property. What you can so is to build your own Widget. But I found an example how you can do it. Look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72117503/7242912

Comment: yea i dont think its possible atm apparently. I suggest showing the result with the (700INR) in a helperText instead. Put a bool value to change to true in the onChanged parameter and show the helperText (controller.text + (700INR) when bool is true

Comment: suffix icon suppose to be in the end of the line right? may be try `textAlign: TextAlign.end`.  or if you want the exact design you can create it by using combination of row, container and text field

Comment: Thanks , Trying with stack and positioned widget

Answer (score 1):

This is an old but if anybody need this is how i solve it. Just wrap the textfield with "IntrinsicWidth" and center it. I hope it helps.

```
Center(
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        onTap: (){},
        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLength: 4,
        maxLines: 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10),
          counterText: "",
          counter: null,
          suffixText: "suffixText",
        ).applyDefaults(
          Theme.of(context).extension<AppStyles>()!.borderlessInputStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

**you can wrap it in a Container widget**

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Amount',
    prefixText: "\$",
    suffix: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 80, // adjust this value as needed
      child: Text("(700INR)"),
    ),
  ),
  controller: amountController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  onSubmitted: (_) => submitData(),
)
```

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: check my answer i will update this